# how to make [load on scroll] to not keep adding images into ram?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, optimization

I'm doing some `load on scroll` in my `UITableView` to fetch data from the server.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let lastElement = self._titles_en.count - 1
    if indexPath.row == lastElement
    {
        page += 1
        searchForString()
    }
}
```

each entry adds a UITableViewCell with a `UIImageView` loaded using [kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

```
loadRemoteImage(placeImage, argURL: _images[indexPath.row], cr : 0)
```

Now my question is, how do I make sure that the ram used don't keep on increasing?

I was watching the ram in debug tools, it increases by 10 mega bytes for about 3 page loads, which is too much, and it's starting to exceed 200 mega bytes, so is there any trick to avoid this ram open increase? I'm afraid of the user keeping scrolling many times and boom, app crash.

Comment: have you profiled to see if you are just leaking images or if they are staying buffered?

Comment: good question @GradyPlayer, can you tell me how I can determine?

Comment: In which method this line of code written :  `loadRemoteImage(placeImage, argURL: _images[indexPath.row], cr : 0)
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AsyncDisplayKit and automatically benefit from intelligent preloading and memory management. In particular, if a cell of an `ASTableNode` includes an image, but that cell is [not likely to be visible soon](http://asyncdisplaykit.org/docs/intelligent-preloading.html) then the image will be purged from memory.

example :
[image: example]

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: I should say that to benefit from the automatic memory purge you should use `ASNetworkImageNode`. It can purge the image because it uses the cache and downloader from its designated initializer to refetch the image either from disk (if cached) or from a remote location.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say optimize your images, a lot. According to what you're saying, you're using very large images. Remember that they are being displayed in a UITableViewCell, so it should be safe to have them compressed.

Try fetching and displaying thumbnails instead of the actual full-sized images. That would improve user experience too, reduce lag, your memory usage!

Comment: i did this, but really need a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add processor to imgage request and shrink images. This will keep your images small. Try this:

```
let processor = ResizingImageProcessor(targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.processor(processor)])
```

Comment: this is useful, but not a detailed answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `SDWebImage` for the same purpose, and it have very simple methods for the same. Also, it provides you the option that do you forcefully wants to load the image or use the cached images if exists.

I have also tried to lookup the memory for the same, in my case with `SDWebImage`, for first 4-5 images, ram increased much, but later on it remained constant.

Comment: I believe kingfisher has this feature, but is hidden or something.